# Some problem about Android Driver Development

Tags: android, driver

I am very new to this field. Actually I just begin to investigate the possibilities.

The simple version of my question is, **what will it take to develop a driver (say USB<->Serial), deploy it to an Android phone (commercial product, not customized one) and write apps to utilize it? Is this even possible?**

And here comes a longer version.

I already have experiences on Windows driver development and some knowledge of Linux driver. And I also did some research. All I know about is NDK. What I don't know is:

1. All reference I found seems to imply driver developing is done when designing the device, not for hacking an exist one. Is that the case?
2. How to deploy if possible? Does the driver has to be integrated with the kernel into a ROM and brush?
3. If the device does not support USB host, is it because the hardware design or just something missing in the software or both?

Sorry for the long question list. Any suggestions regarding this field will help since I have other plans involving building an Android device from scratch. Thanks for your time.

And by the way, ADK is too expensive (at least now) for my application so it's out of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

1., 2. You cannot inject custom driver in unrooted stock ROM. To inject a driver, your users will need to root the device or flash a custom ROM altogether.

3.- It depends on device. Some can do USB host with custom software, some can't.

Check out the [Android Open Accessory Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html). With this you could build a board with serial port that talks with stock Android 2.3.4+ and Android 3.1+ devices via Android accessory protocol.

Comment: Actually you pretty much can inject a driver (or if need be) a new kernel into a stock rom, without recompiling anything else as there's a fairly clear and documented dividing line between the kernel and userspace.  But at a minimum you need root, kernel headers, and if the existing kernel doesn't support modules, the ability to flash a new kernel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It helps and I will gather information from those directions.

Comment: @Chris Thanks. I am very interested those possibilities. It might be the closet outcome to what I am hoping since root is not a problem for my device. Any further information or references would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Honeycomb may provide standardized support for USB host and some functions using it, and many honeycomb devices seem to have the port, but I don't know if there's a standard in honeycomb that says it should ship with the USB<>serial drivers available in the upstream linux kernel.

For all earlier versions, any possibility is going to be device specific and require root access.

ADK is available for the latest Android versions, but as you noted it's a very suboptimal solution, in that it puts all the complexity in the accessory and also requires that to provide bus power, both of which are "backwards" from the usual case.

Comment: Thanks. Since this project will pretty much only work on earlier versions of Android device, anything latest might not be considered.:(

Comment: Though I am wondering where can I find any references on how to do this in earlier versions (no earlier than 2.1).

Comment: USB host possibility on earlier android versions is device specific, do a search on the device name and usb host.  For external devices having their own USB host functionality, people started talking ADB to unmodified android devices before the announcement of the special ADK protocol for the latest releases; AFAIK the "downside" compared to the ADK protocol is that the user has to enable USB debugging, the upside is that most existing devices should be able to support it.

Answer (score 0):

To install a driver will require root.

For an example:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/e1794bdecebb62cc?pli=1